How to toggle between two DataTemplates in Code behind
I have a ResourceDictionary that has two DataTemplates. Each template has a stackpanel with an object.
In my code behind based on a conditionm I get from elsewhere, I want to embed one of those stackpanel's into a placeholder grid. Seems easy enough except I have an ItemClick event that demands a x:class or something.
//toggle.xaml
<ResourceDictionary .....>

   <DataTemplate x:Key="A">
     <StackPanel>
       ..Tab control with certain tabs with a button with a click event
     </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate x:Key="B">
     <StackPanel>
       ..Tab control with with certain button with a click event
     </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>

//in MainWindow.cs

<Window.....>
  <Window.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary Source ="/toggle.xaml"
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid x:Name="myGrid" />
  
</Window>

//in my MainWindow.xaml.cs code behind

var dictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent("/toggle.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
String key = "A";

if (certainConditionExists)
{
   key = "B";
}

var template = (DataTemplate)dictionary[key];
var panel = (StackPanel)template.Resources[key];
myGrid.Children.Add(panel);

Error:
'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file

Actually I was doing way more than I had too. I realized all I had to do was collapse the tab header in one case and display them in another. So I didn't even need two DataTemplates or a datatemplate selector. Just need one Window with a tab control and and a way to collapse the tab headers if needed.

You do not need to call Application.LoadComponent when toggle.xaml is already loaded into Window.Resources. Then you would call the DataTemplate's LoadContent method to create its UI element tree.
var template = (DataTemplate)Resources[key];
var panel = (StackPanel)template.LoadContent();
myGrid.Children.Add(panel);


You may also want to add other resources than those in toggle.xaml to Window.Resources, so write
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/toggle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- more resources here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>


I think the way you chose to solve the problem is questionable. I can't give you any exact conclusions because you haven't written anything about the task itself.
As for the direct answer to your question, there are several possible solutions.
I'll show you two ways:

Static Click Handler.
RoutedCommand with registration.

    public static partial class SomeHelper
    {
        public static RoutedEventHandler SomeClicker { get; } = (s, _) =>
        {
            Button button = (Button)s;
            MessageBox.Show(button.CommandParameter?.ToString(), "Static Clicker");
        };


        private static RoutedUICommand _messageCommand;
        public static RoutedUICommand MessageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_messageCommand == null)
                {
                    _messageCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Show Message", nameof(MessageCommand), typeof(SomeHelper));
                    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), new CommandBinding(_messageCommand, OnMessageExecute));
                }
                return _messageCommand;
            }
        }

        private static void OnMessageExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Parameter?.ToString(), "CommandBinding");
        }
    }

    <Button Content="First"
            Click="{x:Static local:SomeHelper.SomeClicker}"
            CommandParameter="Message One"/>

    <Button Content="Second"
            Command="{x:Static local:SomeHelper.MessageCommand}"
            CommandParameter="Message Two"/>

If necessary, both variants can be combined in one button. In this case, the Click event handler will be executed first, and then the command.

What i didn't convey was the click event of the button does the exact same thing. In one example I'm merely wrapping something in a tab control and on the other if statement there is a button with no tabs. And really it's not a button but some control with a event. In reality I have simplified the example. It is a dock control. But if some configuration file has a value set, then the dock control is in a tab control. Example one, i have a dock control. Example two the dock control is embedded in a tab control.

@JohnGrove
A static handler can be used for any event.
You can also "hang" a command on any event using Behavior.
The gist of my answer is that you need to move the event (or behavior) handling out of Code Behind into a separate class. A static class is the simplest way to implement this approach, but it is not the only one. There are other options.
